# Why has to be size of dynamically-allocated array a static field?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dummy class where I am testing arrays. I've noticed that when I want to dynamically allocate size of array at runtime, fields that indicate this size have to be static. I know I should probably use collections for this kind of code, but I'm more interested why do these fields have to be static? Is there any particular reason behind this?

```
class Foo
{
    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    private int[,] bar = new int[ x, y ];

    public Foo( int a, int b )
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don't really have to be static - it's just that you can't refer to other instance variables within instance variable initializers. In other words, it's a bit like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private int x;
    private int y = x; // Invalid
}
```

From section 10.5.5.2 of the C# 3 spec:

> A variable initializer for an instance
>   field cannot reference the instance
>   being created. Thus, it is a
>   compile-time error to reference this
>   in a variable initializer, as it is a
>   compile-time error for a variable
>   initializer to reference any instance
>   member through a simple-name.

I suspect you really want something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    private int[,] bar;

    public Foo( int a, int b )
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        bar = new int[x, y];
    }
}
```

Of course you don't really need `x` and `y` at all - they're just convenient to keep each dimension of the array. You *could* also use `bar.GetLength(0)` and `bar.GetLength(1)` to get the two lengths, but that's not terribly pleasant.

You might want to rename `x` and `y` to `width` and `height` though, or something similar :)

Answer (score 1):

The example shown of 'Foo will never have the array 'bar be anything but an an array of size [0,0] : it's instantiation occurs before you call the class constructor.

Try this :

```
public class Foo2
{
    private int[,] bar;

    public Foo2(int a, int b)
    {
        bar = new int[a,b];
    }
}
```

That will give you an array of size [a,b] without use of 'static.

Comment: Please note that J. Skeet's prescient comment on Henk's answer would also apply to my first statement above concerning the original class 'Foo.